# How to find all maximum value between every i and i + k(some constant) of a given array?

Tags: dynamic-programming

I need to find all maximum values among elements of every possible set {a[i], a[i+1],... a[i + k]} (where i is index and k is some given constant). For this I am using.

```
loop(b, 1, k) {
       rloopl(i, b, n) {
           if(a[i] < a[i-1])
               a[i] = a[i-1];
       }
}
```

but its too slow for large array. Is there any other more efficient way to do this?

Comment: How is this dynamic programming?

Answer (score 1):

I'm very sorry to tell you that, with the requirement as-presented, the answer would be:  "no."  If "the largest value could be anywhere," you have no choice but to *"look* ... everywhere."

If you are "doing this 'once and only once,'" for any particular data-set, then you're basically just gonna have to take your lumps.  You're *stuck* with "brute-force."

*However,* if you're doing this *more than once,* and/or if you have some influence on the process by which the array in question gets *loaded,* the situation might start looking a little better.

For instance, if another piece of code is adding elements to this array one-at-a-time, it's trivial for that piece of code to notice the max/min value that it encounters.  Code that loads a two-dimensional array might gather statistics about each row (column).  And, so on.  Such strategies, which are "free, at the time," can be used to eliminate (or, severely curtail) the need to do specific brute-force searches later.